# Reduce in-memory usage

Tags: node.js, tcp, concurrency, io, buffer

In my NodeJS app, I'm facing a major issue with some tasks because they require manipulating large amounts of data which cause that the process is sometimes killed by the OS, which I want to avoid of course. And anyhow I want to reduce in-memory consumption because the end client is anyhow TCP connected and storing everything in memory to send it in a bulk doesn't make sense.

The schema is the following:

1. A request arrives on the master process
2. It sends it to 1 or multiple children process of it's choice (to exploit multiple cores for demanding requests like downloading large amounts of data)
3. Child treats it's operation and manipulates those data
4. Child returns some manipulated data to the master
5. Master replies to the request

The number of children is predefined and doesn't change over time. At the moment I'm using IPC to transfer data between parent / child but the content is most of the time over than 100kB so it doesn't make sense to do IPC from what I read in various Stacks.

So what I thought, would be to use some Streams, PIPEs or FIFO (just Mac/Linux usage) to make that run smoothly. But one question remains which is:
How do I do when multiple requests are entering the master process (as master is load balancing requests across children)? I cannot just have one stream per child that could make data overlap. Adding identification to each Buffer sent through the Stream doesn't really make sense neither I guess?

So what would you advice in terms of methodology and then in terms of technology? (PIPEs ? FIFO ? Something else ?)

P.S. : I don't want to give the socket to the child.

P.S.2: If I go with pipes how can the master have individual pipes per child?

Answer (score 0):

You should send the sockets arriving on the parent to a child straightly. Once the child has the socket connection, it can receive the data and the IPC communication between the parent and the child is not used anymore (avoiding overhead). To achieve that, you should use `worker.process.send([data...], sendHandle)` this is really important and you can get the understanding [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback).

```
// --------------
// parent.js
// --------------

// Load the net module to create a tcp server.
var net = require('net');
var child = require('child_process').fork('child.js');

// Creates a new TCP server. The handler argument is automatically set as a listener for the 'connection' event
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // You should add logic to be sure not sending a socket to a child that isn't alive yet..
  child.send({new:'socket connection'}, socket);

});


// --------------
// child.js
// --------------
process.on('message', function (message, socket) {

  socket.on('data', function (d) {
    // Consume your data here
  });

  socket.write('write to client if you want...');

});
```

**/!\ If you intend to use `sendHandle` to send the server instance to multiple workers, be aware that if you want to make `listen` straightly in the workers (all on the same port / server) you will have to use `cluster` and the [Node schedulingPolicy](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy). It is impossible to `listen` in multiple workers on the same port without using `cluster` don't even try it.**

We built a little NPM package to manage that ([load-process-manager](https://github.com/swanest/load-process-manager)) that basically handles the problem.